# Arduino Vehicle Remote Start

Tags: arduino, wiring, diagram

I am really intrigued in the idea of designing a remote start using an Arduino and Bluetooth connectivity.

I plan to wire a relay to the starter switch of a motorbike. I have chosen to do it this way instead of directly wiring it to the motor because the bike already has built in safety to make sure it wont crank whilst in gear and will cut off once the engine is running.

Here I have a rough diagram of what I plan to do, please keep in mind I have very little experience on how electricity 'really' works so besides splicing some cables I have no idea if this would work.

[image]

1. Would this setup work?
2. Would this allow for normal fail-safe functionality in-case the relay failed or some other malfunction?
3. My primary concern having little electronic knowledge is would this kind of 'bypass' work where the starter switch skips past the relay, what if they were both activated at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work if you connect the relay exactly parallel to the starter switch poles. Make sure you do not bypass other circuitry, which could contain some safety mechanism. Also I would recommend doing this with a experienced/professional electrician, for your own safety.

Regarding the follow-up question, since they are connected in parallel, it would not make a difference if both the relay and the switch are activated at the same time. The starter will run when the relay **OR** the switch is activated.